# In EM derivation why can I sum over the iid variables in the conditional expectation?

Tags: machine-learning, expected-value, conditional-expectation, expectation-maximization

In EM when you take the expectation:

$E[\log P(y,x \mid \theta)\mid x, \theta']$

$= \sum\limits_yP(y\mid x, \theta') \log P(y,x\mid \theta)$

I understand this but the following part I don't understand. We know that $x$ is a vector of $n$ independent identically distributed variables. Also y is a single value- the cluster x is assigned to.

How is the above equivalent to:

=$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\sum\limits_y P_{\theta'}(y\mid x_i)log P_\theta(y,x_i)$

I realize that multiplication within a log expands to summation but how does one replace $P_{\theta'}(y\mid x)$ with $P_\theta'(y,x_i)$?

Reference: slide 13
http://cs.nyu.edu/~eugenew/publications/em-talk.pdf

Answer (score 2):

For iid data points $\boldsymbol{x}=x_i,\ldots,x_n$, the complete data log-likelihood is

$$\ell(\theta)=\mathrm{log}[\prod_{i=1}^nP(y,x_i|\theta)]=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathrm{log}P(y,x_i|\theta).$$

The $Q$ function is defined as $$Q(\theta,\theta^{'})=E(\ell(\theta)|\boldsymbol{x},\theta^{'})=\sum_{i=1}^nE[\mathrm{log}P(y,x_i|\theta)|x_i,\theta^{'}].$$

For each data point $x_i$, you have understood that $$E[\mathrm{log}P(y,x_i|\theta)|x_i,\theta^{'}]=\sum_yP(y|x_i,\theta^{'})\mathrm{log}P(y,x_i|\theta).$$

Thus $$Q(\theta,\theta^{'})=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_yP(y|x_i,\theta^{'})P(y,x_i|\theta)=\sum_{i=1}^n\Sigma_yP_{\theta^{'}}(y|x_i)P_\theta(y,x_i).$$